# Java: reconnect disconnected network share

Tags: java, networking, network-share

Windows XP on reboot doesn't automatically reconnect my network shares, Windows 7 only does it if the wifi connects fast enough, otherwise it fails and leaves them disconnected.

Usually when one of the two behaviors happen I just go to "computer resources" and double click on the network share drive and this automatically reconnects if the network connection is available.

Now how can a Java program try reconnecting the disconnected network shares it needs?
Right now my program simply fails so I have to double click manually the network share's drive and restart my java program.

Comment: did u find a solution back then?

Answer (score -2):

To map a drive from a command prompt, and have it remain after a reboot, is to make it persistent.No need to write a java program.

[NET USE  \computername\share -p]

Or, right click on My Computer, click map network drive, choose the location, and make sure "Reconnect at logon"

Hope this would help you

Comment: My question is specific to a Java program and it's tagged so. I'm not looking how to solve the network share problem under Windows but specifically how can a Java program behave as described.